# Is this a good camera: Canon PowerShot SX130IS?

Tags: canon, powershot

Canon PowerShot SX130IS: Have you used/experienced this camera?  What do you have to say about it?  Thanks!

Intended/planned use:

- outdoor photography (85% of the time)
- Macro subjects
- far away subjects
- mostly during the day - but sometimes early morning/evenings (sunset/sunrises)

Comment: It would be useful to include details of what sort of thing you're going to be using it for.

Comment: @Rowland Shaw: thanks for the suggestion, see updated post...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I bought one as a gift and the owner is very happy with it. I cannot vouch first-hand on image quality but I found it an excellent value because it is one of the cheapest modern cameras with full manual controls, a wide-angle lens and AA batteries, particularly since Canon has been removing manual controls from their A-series. I'd say there aren't too many cameras this capable for such a low price.

Naturally, whether it's good for you depends on your needs. This type of camera is generally not so good for low-light and action because it responds slower and the lack of an optical viewfinder makes following action difficult. On the other hand, if you are travelling and shooting mostly in daylight you should have little to worry about.

Comment: Thanks a lot! exactly the kind of info i was looking for...+1!

Comment: @Queso: I know, I am a veteran Stack Exchange user, but was waiting to see for more answers... :)

Comment: Cool, I am with ya